# What is a right way to use servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, forms, servlets, ejb-3.0

I'm studying EJB3.

I have a session bean which provides services to create/update customer accounts.

This session bean offers services on the lines of:

```
public void addCustomer(Customer c);
public void updateCustomer(Customer c);
```

Ideally I'd like to have a single servlet: CustomerServlet and it would invoke the session beans that I have listed above.

Problem is that I have two JSPs: UpdateAccount.jsp and CreateAccount.jsp. Both of these JSPs have a form with a method POST and action "CustomerServlet".

How can I distinguish in a customer servlet which operation I should carry out: createAccount or updateAccount?

I guess the alternative is to have a separate servlet for each operation...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really certain about the best practice for this but I have a couple of suggestions that might work:

1. If your form is being submitted using a submit button, you could distinguish the request on the basis of the value of the <button-name> parameter. So if your buttons had the values `Update` and `Create` and were named `account-submit`, by checking the value you get with `request.getParameter('account-submit')`, you'd be able to tell which button was clicked to generate this request. If you named them differently, you could also just check which of the two parameters was not null and you'd know which form submit you were handling.

   Note that if you have only a single text field in your form and the user hits `Enter` instead of clicking the button, you'll get a `null` in your servlet! See [my blog post about this behaviour.](http://tipsandtricks.nogoodatcoding.com/2007/07/html-single-text-field-submit-caveat.html)
2. Check the `Referer` header - I wouldn't really recommend this since you wouldn't always know the context of the deployed app, this value may not always be present and it can be easily spoofed.
3. Add another mapping for your servlet so that it's accessible at both http://myapp.example.com/context/create and http://myapp.example.com/context/update. You can then check the `ServletPath` (`request.getServletPath()`) to see what 'servlet' the request came in for. I'd probably go with this one since it seems the most robust to me but you might also want to add the other two checks just to make sure. In your `web.xml`, you'd want something like

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CreateUpdateServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.CustomerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CreateUpdateServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/create</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CreateUpdateServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/update</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Good to see you here as well!

Comment: Thank you your reply. You didn't say anything about my idea of using a different servlet for each operation. E.g. create-account form would post to CreateAccountServlet and update-account form would post to UpdateAccountServlet. Is that a poor decision?

Comment: @BalusC - You too! I've been seeing your answers here but I've only just had some free time (back in school :)) so I've been on SO for a couple of days. Not sure how long I can keep it up though!

Comment: @vikp - You certainly could do that. I'd base the decision on how much of the code/logic can be shared between the two operations. If it's a lot, then it might be more maintainable to have them both in one servlet with simple checks for where they differ. However, if you find that it ends up making the code unreadable or unmanageable, then it might be better to split them completely and perhaps use helper classes/methods for the common functionality. I'm not familiar with EJB, but I imagine your business logic already resides in a bean so having just one serlvet might be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

JSPs **are** Servlets, just in a different source code form, there is no reason to `POST` to a different Servlet, you can just `POST` back to the same JSP.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.The question is how can two different JSPs post to the same servlet?

Comment: lollipop - I would disagree with your suggestion for POSTing to a JSP - JSPs are meant to be used for presentation and shouldn't (usually) have any business logic in them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the servlet. JSPs (or Facelets) can talk directly to the beans via EL.